# What happened to remaining 12 upgradable packages?

Tags: linux, debian, upgrade, apt

So, yesterday night, I ran an `apt update` which reported that 15 packages could be upgraded. I issues the `apt upgrade` command immediately and started upgrading the packages

```
docker-ce ffmpeg libavcodec57 libavcodec57:i386 libavdevice57 libavfilter6 libavformat57 libavresample3 libavresample3:i386
libavutil55 libavutil55:i386 libpostproc54 libswresample2 libswresample2:i386 libswscale4
```

The internet connection seemed slow at that time, so I decided to skip downloading large package (docker), and decided to just install/upgrade `libavutil55` which had already been downloaded.

After its installation finished, I slept. Waking up today morning, I decided to upgrade the rest of them as the internet connection seemed stable. But lo-and-behold; apt is now only upgrading `docker-ce` and nothing else.

Below is the transcript of the commands; the `alias`es used are:

```
ad='sudo apt update'
ag='sudo apt upgrade'
ai='sudo apt install'
```

---

```
┌┤✅├─┤ hjpotter92 ├─┤~│
└┴─ ⚡[▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶] ┴─ ➜ ad
Hit:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg InRelease
Hit:2 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x stretch InRelease
Hit:3 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:7 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:9 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview InRelease
Hit:10 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Ign:11 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:12 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:13 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:14 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-backports InRelease
Hit:15 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch Release
Get:17 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease [39.1 kB]
Hit:18 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
Fetched 39.1 kB in 8s (4,542 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
15 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
┌┤✅├─┤ hjpotter92 ├─┤~│
└┴─ ⚡[▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶] ┴─ ➜ au
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  docker-ce ffmpeg libavcodec57 libavcodec57:i386 libavdevice57 libavfilter6 libavformat57 libavresample3 libavresample3:i386
  libavutil55 libavutil55:i386 libpostproc54 libswresample2 libswresample2:i386 libswscale4
15 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 53.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 16.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 libavutil55 amd64 7:3.2.11-1~deb9u1 [218 kB]
Get:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 docker-ce amd64 18.06.0~ce~3-0~debian [40.1 MB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 libavutil55 i386 7:3.2.11-1~deb9u1 [236 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 libswresample2 amd64 7:3.2.11-1~deb9u1 [98.0 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 libswresample2 i386 7:3.2.11-1~deb9u1 [103 kB]
Get:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 libavcodec57 i386 7:3.2.11-1~deb9u1 [4,432 kB]
12% [2 docker-ce 1,810 kB/40.1 MB 5%] [6 libavcodec57:i386 1,710 kB/4,432 kB 39%]                                  49.8 kB/s 16min 31s^C
┌┤✘ ├─┤ hjpotter92 ├─┤~│
└┴─ ⚡[▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶] ┴─ ➜ ai libavutil55
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libavutil55:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libavutil55 libavutil55:i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/454 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 322125 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libavutil55_7%3a3.2.11-1~deb9u1_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libavutil55:amd64 (7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1) ...
Unpacking libavutil55:i386 (7:3.2.11-1~deb9u1) over (7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libavutil55_7%3a3.2.11-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavutil55:amd64 (7:3.2.11-1~deb9u1) over (7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1) ...
Setting up libavutil55:amd64 (7:3.2.11-1~deb9u1) ...
Setting up libavutil55:i386 (7:3.2.11-1~deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
┌┤✅├─┤ hjpotter92 ├─┤~│
└┴─ ⚡[▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶] ┴─ ➜ au
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  docker-ce
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 40.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 16.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 docker-ce amd64 18.06.0~ce~3-0~debian [40.1 MB]
Fetched 40.1 MB in 1min 39s (405 kB/s)
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 322125 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../docker-ce_18.06.0~ce~3-0~debian_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce (18.06.0~ce~3-0~debian) over (18.03.1~ce-0~debian) ...
Setting up docker-ce (18.06.0~ce~3-0~debian) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
┌┤✅├─┤ hjpotter92 ├─┤~│
└┴─ ⚡[▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶] ┴─ ➜ ad
Ign:1 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Get:4 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:7 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:8 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Hit:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:10 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x stretch InRelease
Hit:11 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview InRelease
Hit:12 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
Hit:13 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:14 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg InRelease
Get:16 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-backports InRelease [91.8 kB]
Hit:17 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch Release
Get:18 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages.diff/Index [27.8 kB]
Hit:15 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Get:20 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-backports/main i386 Packages.diff/Index [27.8 kB]
Get:21 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-07-19-2007.59.pdiff [217 B]
Get:21 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages 2018-07-19-2007.59.pdiff [217 B]
Get:22 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-backports/main i386 Packages 2018-07-19-2007.59.pdiff [464 B]
Get:23 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-backports/main i386 Packages 2018-07-20-0209.59.pdiff [216 B]
Get:23 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-backports/main i386 Packages 2018-07-20-0209.59.pdiff [216 B]
Fetched 334 kB in 4s (71.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
┌┤✅├─┤ hjpotter92 ├─┤~│
└┴─ ⚡[▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶▶] ┴─ ➜ au
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

What happened to the remaining packages?

Comment: Do you have `unattended-upgrades` installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that [`unattended-upgrades`](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) upgraded most of your packages.

`docker-ce` wasn't automatically upgraded because by default, packages from third-party repositories aren't automatically upgraded.

For a lot of the most recent unattended upgrades, see the `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log` file.

Comment: Yes. Checking the log file shows that unattended-upgrades has upgraded packages twice in 2 months. I have now set the `Unattended-Upgrade::Mail` so that I'd atleast be aware of autoupdates :)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by @Deltik docker is a third party repository. I just faced the same problem and found out how to easily add any repository you are using on your machine.

First enter the following command:

```
apt-cache policy
```

This will give you a list of all different repositories you are using on your debian installation. 
Docker for example will show as the following line under Debian 9 (Stretch)

```
500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages release 
o=Docker,a=stretch,l=Docker CE,c=stable,b=amd64 origin download.docker.com
```

Copy the following part of the line into the UnattendedUpgrades configuration file which is located at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` and put it into the section `Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern`: (Make sure to leave out the `b` parameter as it is not supported)

```
"o=Docker,a=stretch,l=Docker CE,c=stable";
```

To check if everything is working as expected use the following command to debug your configuration:

```
unattended-upgrade -d
```

If there is no error then all the packages will be upgraded or a message telling you that there are no packages to be upgraded will be displayed.